# how to change this query influxdb "error rate" to "success rate" to display on grafana?

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I already download dashboard from plugin grafana, only show error rate and i found query error rate from panel. i plan to modify little bit query to show success rate on grafana dashboard. if you don't mind please help me to modify query

i already modify

```
SELECT sum("count") FROM "$measurement_name" WHERE ( "application" =~ /^$application$/ AND "statut" = 'ok')  AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)
```

and this the original query from plugin grafana.

```
SELECT sum("error") / sum("all") FROM (SELECT sum("count") AS "all" FROM "$measurement_name" WHERE "transaction" = 'all' AND "application" =~ /^$application$/ AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)), (SELECT sum("countError") AS "error" FROM "$measurement_name" WHERE "transaction" = 'all' AND "application" =~ /^$application$/ AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null))
```

i expect the output of 80% success but actual output is 216400.00%

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this without subqueries.  Try something like this first just to make sure count and countError are what you expect:

```
SELECT sum("count"),sum("countError") 
FROM "$measurement_name" 
WHERE "transaction" = 'all' AND "application" =~ /^$application$/ AND $timeFilter 
GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)
```

Then you can issue a single query where you divide them:

```
SELECT sum("count")/sum("countError") 
FROM "$measurement_name" 
WHERE "transaction" = 'all' AND "application" =~ /^$application$/ AND $timeFilter 
GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for the Success Rate %, so after acquiring some knowledge on 'AS' and 'Sub Queries' I was able to resolve.

The formula for Success Rate % : (Total Requests / Total Passed Requests) * 100

The answer to your question is the following query :

```
    SELECT sum("success") / sum("all") FROM (SELECT sum("count") AS "all" FROM "$measurement_name" WHERE "transaction" = 'all' AND "application" =~ /^$application$/ AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)), (SELECT sum("count")-sum("countError")  AS "success" FROM "$measurement_name" WHERE "transaction" = 'all' AND "application" =~ /^$application$/ AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null))
```

Here, the second query fetches you the "Total Passed Requests" and using 'AS' to alias the query as 'success'.

```
    (SELECT sum("count")-sum("countError")  AS "success" FROM "$measurement_name" WHERE "transaction" = 'all' AND "application" =~ /^$application$/ AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null))
```

Where, the first query fetches you the "Total Requests" and using 'AS' to alias the query as 'all'.

```
    (SELECT sum("count") AS "all" FROM "$measurement_name" WHERE "transaction" = 'all' AND "application" =~ /^$application$/ AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null))
```

Now, the initial part of the query:

```
   SELECT sum("success") / sum("all")
```

actually divides the above mentioned two queries : Total Requests / Total Passed Requests 
and the '*100' can be done in the "Visualization" section of the graph in grafana by choosing Unit : percent(0.0-0.1)

Hope, this answers your question !